# Questions about "languish."

Tags: questions

I have a few questions about the verb 'to languish.'

1. In the OED, it suggests that this word must be used for a living thing.  Couldn't it be used metaphorically for something like an idea or a literary genre that has a kind of "life?"
2. Most usage suggests that languish cannot have an object. Can't languish be used with a prepositional phrase (with an object of course), for instance?  Can something languish into a pale imitation of itself?  This usage (languish into) was more common 200 years ago but has almost died out according to ngram. Any ideas on why?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

(sorry, couldn't find any decent tags, no usage tag?)

Comment: Hey Rick.  I think you meant to ask this on the main site ([Main]); this "grayish limbo" place is the "Meta" site, which hosts questions of administration etc. That's why you couldn't find the tags you expect.

Comment: Oh dear, yes indeed.  How did "ask a question" lead me here? Is it okay just to repost or is that considered a faux pas?

Comment: I flagged the question to have a mod move it for you, but no one seems to be on duty at the moment.  It's perfectly fine to re-ask it on the main site.

Comment: Actually (@Dan) it's not perfectly fine to post the same question on two sites. What should happen is that the question is moved, which can be done by flagging or by users voting to move it [in the vote-to-close process]. It's far more work clearing up reposts **and** you get a closed question on the main site (which probably won't matter in your case because you shouldn't trigger the automatic question ban, but might matter to other users).

Comment: @AndrewLeach My mistake then. I figured we would simply delete the Meta question. And sorry to have misled you, Rick.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I'm confused about why no one can simply delete this question. According to  [How does deleting work?...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) : "You can typically delete your own posts at will ... Moderators can delete any post instantly." Why aren't exact duplicates or mistaken questions like this just deleted? In the future, if I accidentally post a question on Meta, is there a reason I should wait for people to migrate it, rather than just deleting it and re-asking on the main site?